# What type of events does Backbone use for it's internals?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I thought backbone used events to communicate between its internal components.

What type of events does it use relative to this MDN Doc.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.createEvent

Also, where is it in the source, I did a search for createEvent and nothing came up.

http://backbonejs.org/

Answer (score 2):

All of the information is available by reading the annotated source code on the Backbone site.  The MDN site is entirely irrelevant as it is events that will be fired in Web browser JS and therefore subject to be handled by the browser.  It is only one possible solution for pub/sub and does not universally apply. As Backbone is designed to be able to be run outside of a browser, it handles events itself (again..very early on in the [annotated source code](http://backbonejs.org/docs/backbone.html)).